# Python flask sqlalchemy order_by a math expression - not recognizing table value as float

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to order my query by a math expression for a radius filter:

That is what I need, but the column `zimmer_lat` and `zimmer_lng` are not recognized here as the columns from the Zimmer object but as strings which leads to a `float expected error`. Making a typecast to float - `float('zimmer_lat')`leads to a `cannot cast string to float error`.

```
all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.join(User).filter_by(bezahlt=True).order_by(asc(acos(sin(loc_latitude) * sin('zimmer_lat') + cos(loc_latitude) * cos('zimmer_lat') * cos('zimmer_lng' - (loc_longitude))) * 6371))
```

Here is works and `zimmer_lat` is recognized a float:

```
all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.join(User).filter_by(bezahlt=True).order_by(asc('zimmer_lat'))
```

Comment: Well, `'zimmer_lat'` is a string and so of course you cannot pass it to `math.cos`. You need to look up the equivalent function for cosine in your database engine and use e.g. `func.cos(Zimmer.zimmer_lat)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I had to remove the Join with the User, I found a solution which works and even lets me sort the results by radius. Thanks @univerio for the hint with the func().

I had to use `filter()` instead of `filter_by()`.

If someone knows **how to keep the Join with the User**, let me know please.

Solution:

```
all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.filter(func.acos(func.sin(loc_latitude) * func.sin(Zimmer.zimmer_lat) + func.cos(loc_latitude) * func.cos(Zimmer.zimmer_lat) * func.cos(Zimmer.zimmer_lng - (loc_longitude))) * 6371 <= 2000).order_by(asc(func.acos(func.sin(loc_latitude) * func.sin(Zimmer.zimmer_lat) + func.cos(loc_latitude) * func.cos(Zimmer.zimmer_lat) * func.cos(Zimmer.zimmer_lng - (loc_longitude))) * 6371))
```